# How can I pan single application's audio?

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, settings, alsa

Using the **Sound Settings** window (**last tab**) I can adjust all applications' audio volume, independently from others. Can I in a similar way **adjust** their **stereo** panning?

What exactly I would like to do, is to play music with Banshee or YouTube through the REAR speakers only (I have 5.1 speakers) and my game's sounds through FRONT speakers.

Is that achievable?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It can very easily be done with [PulseAudio Volume Control](http://freedesktop.org/software/pulseaudio/pavucontrol//) ([pavucontrol](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pavucontrol) [image: Install pavucontrol])

[image: screenshot]
Make sure the paddlock ([image: lock icon]) is unlocked when changing the balance

Comment: Perfect! That's exactly what I was looking for! **Great thanks!** Now is there any chance it would allow me to tune all 4 channels (front/back too)? Even if switched output mode to 4.0 it still shows me just two "front" sliders.... :-)

Comment: @rafalcieslak As per [this article](http://drona.csa.iisc.ernet.in/~uday/surround-pulse.shtml) it seems possible. _(I do not own a surround capable audio card to check)._  [This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pavucontrol/+bug/519374) report seems to indicate you need to use an analogue output to get the rear speakers not duplicate the front ones

Comment: Yay, nice finds! Unluckily, this allows just to get all channel sliders for the global mixer, but for particular applications it shows only two. Maybe this is a bug too?

Comment: Couldn't tell. Sad it doesn't fix your problem. I can't seem to find that much information on pavucontrol. Good luck getting it working ! :)